# Почему пропадает сигнал ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, потоки-данных, youtube, rtmp

Использую следующий код для стриминга

```
ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://server" -vcodec libx264 -x264opts "keyint=3:min-keyint=2:no-scenecut" -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 96k -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1920x1080 rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1/ID
```

Качество потока первые ~10 секунд -- высокое, однако потом становится "НЕТ ДАННЫХ" и появляется ошибка "
Не удается получить данные от видеокодера. Проверьте его параметры в настройках трансляции.", хотя ffmpeg продолжает работать.

Answer (score 4):

1. уберите `-re`
2. почитайте, может поможет: http://htrd.su/wiki/zhurnal/2014/09/24/x264_low_latency

если коротко, то, похоже, у вас кодирование требует больше времени, чем выделяется на кадр в рамках FPS. Это косвенно подтверждается тем, что первые 10 сек работает нормально: какое-то число данных может забуфферизироваться. Т.е. вам нужно поиграться с опциями кодирования, которые влияют на время кодирования.

Comment: В этой статье основной упор на уменьшение задержки, а мне задержка абсолютно не важна -- можно хоть секунд 60 выставить, главное чтобы работало 24/7 и картинка была более менее плавная и четкая.

Comment: это наводка. Сам процесс кодирования тоже требует времени и от различных установок это время может различаться - стоит обратить на это внимание. Кроме того, стоит проверить выходной тракт вещая из файла, но задав параметры для кодека copy (опция `-re` в данном случае будет обязательно) - будут ли проблемы в данном случае.

Comment: Я об этом думал уже днем, вот что прикинул: ffmpeg -i "rtmp://live.chnpp.gov.ua/strmr-hoyat1/orig-hoyat1" -codec copy -f flv rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1/ID . Нормально? Приеду домой через пару часов - протестирую

Answer (score 0):

Отправляю видео поток с IP-камеры на youtube/live , правда без звука. По идее, звук тоже должен идти таким способом (не пробовал).

Для начала, надо поставить свежий ffmpeg, тот что идёт в Ubuntu 16.04 у меня периодически зависал при трансляции.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg libav-tools x264 x265
```

Затем скрипт, который перезапускает ffmpeg в случае обрыва сети.

```
nano ffmpeg.sh

MIN_CPU_LOAD=1
CPU=$( top -bn 1 | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n +8 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}')
if [ "$MIN_CPU_LOAD" -gt  "$CPU" ] 
    then
        kill -KILL $(pgrep ffmpeg)
        sleep 10
        ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.64:554 -tune zerolatency -vcodec copy -t 12:00:00 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key> &
fi
```

Делаем файл исполняемым

```
chmod 777 ffmpeg.sh
```

И прописываем задание в cron

```
sudo crontab -e
* * * * * /home/user/ffmpeg.sh
0 4 * * *  reboot
```

У меня отдельный компьютер, который занимается только отправкой видео. Поэтому, скрипт максимально простой.

Логика работы такая. Каждую минуту cron запускает скрипт, если процессор не загружен, перезапускается ffmpeg, так-же происходит запуск после загрузки компьютера.  Раз в сутки, в 4 утра перезапускается компьютер, на всякий случай.

Параметр -t 12:00:00 - задаёт максимальное время работы ffmpeg, где-то читал что время трансляции youtube ограничивает 12 часами.

Вроде всё работает, поток уходит 16Мбит/с, нагрузка процессора низкая т.к. ffmpeg только перепаковывает поток.

Для наблюдения, удобно использовать atop и htop

```
sudo apt install atop htop
```